# WPFToolkit.DLL indicate WPF app?

Tags: wpf

Would the presence of `WPFToolkit.dll` in an application's folder indicate that it is a WPF app?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if it`s a desktop application, WPFToolkit.dll library **may** suggest that it`s WPF application. 
If it was not copied or added as project reference by mistake, of course. And if that`s not an WinForms app using some WPF elements. And if that`s not some random library that author chose to name this way.

Anyways, that`s probably an WPF app alright.

Answer (score 0):

As icebat said, it probably is.

Though you can use Process Explorer to see if the WPFToolkit.dll is loaded by the application while it's up to be sure.